# bootstrap 4 tooltip not working with angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

why the below line getting error . i am using bootstrap 4 with angular 7

error description: error TS2339: Property 'tooltip' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

```
   ngAfterViewInit() {
      jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
   }
```

please let me know if any one know answer.

Comment: Before `@Component` have you declare jQyery? `declare let jQuery`

Comment: Try instead of using the name `JQuery` directly to `declare const $;` before component declaration and use `$`.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, i added declare let jQuery , error rectified thanks. But tooltip showing as normal css tooltip not bootstrap tooltip

Comment: @Santhosh import bootstrap CSS in either `angular.json` or in `styles.scss` file

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, i have already added bootstrap css as below      "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],

Comment: Try rebuilding the app or check the path. Otherwise, import in styles.scss

Answer (score 1):

use this [ng2-tooltip-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive) this is very easy to implement in your application

stackblitz : [example](https://angular-8k8mmp.stackblitz.io/)